# CiviMRF, Drupal 7, Webforms: Form Processor File Url could not be created

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, form-processor

Gurus out there, I get an error adding a file upload field in drupal 7 webforms, when enabling the "Form Processor File Url" wrapper, something like "Directory cmrfformprocessor://webform/my-name could not be created. Please make sure directory is writable".

I tried to create every directory combination under sites/default/files, but nothing helped. Made sites/ writable for apache-user recursively but no luck. Read the civimrf and cmrf_form_processor source code without getting a clue.

Could you help me out?

Drupal, all modules and CiviCRM are current stable versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know, how this ever worked. Webform module checks for the schemed directory path always, even if - like in this case - the streamwrapper is mapped to an external API and not to the local filesystem.

So changing

```
public function mkdir($uri, $mode, $options) {
    return FALSE;
}
```

to

```
public function mkdir($uri, $mode, $options) {
    return TRUE;
}
```

in `cmrf_form_processor_stream_wrapper.inc` fixes the issue.